# What Are The Steps For Bigneers To Create Google Map Web App Using Java Language (New Bie)

Tags: java, jsp, google-maps, web-applications, servlets

i have worked using .Net i do not know about java can you please let me know the ID for java development that would be more compatible for bigneer and tell the versions of the software also with its pre requset and what is more useful for java development jsp or servlet

Hopes for your suggestions i wanna develop java web app demo using google map api so please let me know about what google api would be use and if possible then mention me the links for the software and API for downlaoding ..

Regards,

Comment: Please learn to walk before you try to run: learn the basics, search this site (and Google) for info on how to get started with Java. Do a few tutorials, learn how to write a simple Hello World and some simple webapps. **Then** try to find out how to use Google Maps in your Java webapps. You **can't** learn all of it at once.

Comment: i have develop a hello world app using ecllips ide but now what should i do to develop java web app or from whom either with JSP or Servler?

Comment: Don't you think that these **exact** question ("How do I develop a Java web app?" and "Should I use JSP or Servlets?") haven't been asked **tons** of times before and have *perfectly good* answers already?

Comment: humm.. ok let me know that what should i use jsp or servlet ? which is easy and more efficient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well For working with java eclipse IDE is the most preferred way to start with 
here is the download link for the latest build from Eclipse

[Eclipse Download link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/R/eclipse-jee-indigo-win32.zip)

You need not to install eclipse all you need to extract it at some place of your choice and click on the eclipse.exe file and you are ready to go.
before that you need to have JDK in your  system .download JDK from the oracle and install in your machine

[Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

For running JSP/Servlet you need a container so Jetty/Tomcat will do the things for you, Tomcat being the most popular is my suggestion

download Tomcat from Apache tomcat site and install it
[Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)

Remember the installation should be

1. 1  JDK
2. Eclipse , Tomcat

For creating a web application in your eclipse follow
File-NewProject->DyanmicProject 
and follow the wizard

For creating a Google map all you need to register your self with Google map API and get a key from them which is used as authentication for every request being sent by your application to the Google map API

follow the step mentioned in the link to get a key from Google map API

[Sign Up for the Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html)

here is the step by step guide from Google Map API itself how to use the Google map API to get data from the Google map and display it.

Remember Google Map API is java script based and for display purpose you need to know a bit of java script to play around it.

[Google Map API tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html)

Comment: Thanks alot for giving me some time and after reading your post its getting simple for me to develop web app in java now i am going to develop let see what would happen Thanks alot once again :) !

Comment: welcome..just to add some thing extra here is the link showing step by step way how to develop a web-application in eclipse with tomcat..     http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/

Comment: i have already download and installed (eclipse-java-galileo-SR1-win32.zip) is it fine ? or i have to download the version that you have recommended me ?

Comment: what you have downloaded is perfectly fine no need to download again.